# .local is accessible port 3000 not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webserver, localhost, port

I'm trying to connect my iPhone/iPad to localhost:3000 which runs my rails app.
With my older mac I could access it easily through ben.local
Since my battery just exploded on that old laptop, I cannot even see the settings (seriously, I'm not making this up).
I imagine I went to ben.local:3000

But with my new laptop, running Mavericks, that does not work.

I enabled apache (web sharing, right?) so I can see the enthusiastic "It works!" page on ben.local, but ben.local:3000 does not show me the app. Also on my laptop it doesn't. In fact, on the laptop, I can only access it through localhost:3000 and 127.0.0.1:3000

Indeed, I can use ngrok, but prefer not to.

Any ideas how I can access the app at ben.local:3000?

Answer (score 6):

OK, so here's what you do if you face this issue:

Run your rails server on the ip address of your network.
on a Mac - ifconfig or go to sys prefs and then Network. It will show you what your network ip address is.

Then in Terminal start your rails server and replace the X with your ip address:

```
rails s -b XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

Then on your mobile device go to that ip address on port 3000, so XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000

Make sure your mobile and your local computer are on the same network, of course.